# Confusion Matrix error

Tags: r

I want to build a predictive model using decision tree classification in R.
but I got an error msg (Error: could not find function "confusionMatrix"??) when I run This line:

```
cmatrix <- confusionMatrix(predictions, worktest$YesNo)
```

what thats mean?
please help me.

```
the dput() output:
> dput(worktest$ICUtransfer)
Error in worktest$ICUtransfer : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> dput(ICUtransfer)
Error in dput(ICUtransfer) : object 'ICUtransfer' not found
> dput(worktest)
c(2L, 15L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 34L, 36L, 37L, 39L, 41L)
> dput(fitted)
structure(c(0.689655172413793, 0.689655172413793, 0.689655172413793, 
0.454545454545455, 0.689655172413793, 0.454545454545455, 0.689655172413793, 
0.454545454545455, 0.689655172413793, 0.689655172413793, 0.310344827586207, 
0.310344827586207, 0.310344827586207, 0.545454545454546, 0.310344827586207, 
0.545454545454546, 0.310344827586207, 0.545454545454546, 0.310344827586207, 
0.310344827586207), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("2", 
"15", "19", "20", "21", "34", "36", "37", "39", "41"), c("no", 
"yes")))
>
```

Comment: The `confusionMatrix` function I believe you want is part of the `caret` package.  Make sure it is loaded or try `caret::confusionMatrix(predictions, worktest$YesNo)`

Comment: now it gave this error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Are your data `character` or `factor` types?  Check with `str`

Comment: YesNo is factor w/2 levels "no", "yes"

Comment: and `predictions`?  Can you just provide the `dput` for each object?  Then I can try to reproduce your error.

Comment: fitted <- predict(tree, DataYesNo[worktest, c(input,target)])    cmatrix <- confusionMatrix(fitted, worktest$YesNo)

Comment: Call `dput` on your objects and edit your question to have the available.  For example `dput(predictions)` and copy output to your question.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by objects? input variables or the mode or what?

Comment: The variables you are trying to put in to `confusionMatrix`.  I cannot reproduce your error unless you provide reproducible data.  `dput(predictions)` and `dput(worktest$YesNo)`

Comment: I added the output to question post

Answer (score 3):

Try loading `library(caret)` lib. You may get some error in my case I see as.

```
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: ggplot2
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
Error: package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded
```

It shows actually it fails to load `Rcpp` package so you need to install it

Solution: `install.packages("Rcpp")`

Answer (score 2):

Install these two packages:

```
install.packages('e1071', dependencies=TRUE)

install.packages('caret', dependencies=TRUE)
```